# Oracle :SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
String req="INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS VALUES(6,1,sysdate,'toz',02542,'bporp')(SELECT valide from mouvement where valide=?)";
```

I want to make a request with Conditions but I get the error:

> SQL command not properly ended

Comment: i'm using PreparedStatement

Comment: `  String req="INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS VALUES(6,1,sysdate,'toz',02542,'bporp')(SELECT valide from mouvement where valide=?)";
                            PreparedStatement pst=connexion.getcon().prepareStatement(req);
                            pst.setBoolean(1,valide);
                            ResultSet R=pst.executeQuery();`

Comment: You should still execute a single SQL statement per `PreparedStatement`. This, to me, looks like two SQL statements: an "insert" and a "select". What are you expecting to happen, and what is really happening? (Also, with a handful more lines you could show how you are actually executing this... that might be helpful.)

Comment: @jradich1234  i have error  : SQL command not properly ended

Comment: May be the table name is spelled wrongly and try to give some more details about the error

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza not worth talking about nothing I understand you

Answer (score 3):

You have an invalid SQL query. Here's your current SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS VALUES(6,1,sysdate,'toz',02542,'bporp')(SELECT valide from mouvement where valide=?)
```

If we split this into several lines for better understanding, you will have this:

```
INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS
VALUES(6,1,sysdate,'toz',02542,'bporp')
(SELECT valide from mouvement where valide=?)
```

Which is not a valid statement, not even for any SQL tool. That's because you have 2 statements without separating them: an `INSERT` and then a `SELECT`, and you're not executing an `INSERT INTO <TABLE1> SELECT ... FROM <TABLE2>`.

You should execute a single SQL statement per `Statement` or `PreparedStatement`. This, in Java, should be done like this:

```
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS"
    + " VALUES(6,1,sysdate,'toz',02542,'bporp')";
String sql2 = "SELECT valide from mouvement where valide=?";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
pstmt.setString(1, <parameter_value>);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```